# Are all adjacency matrices of connected graph diagonalizable?

Tags: matrices, graph-theory

The related question has been asked in the following link:
[Are all adjacency matrices (graph theory) diagonalizables?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1403276/are-all-adjacency-matrices-graph-theory-diagonalizables)

However, the answer does not give a formal proof or explicit answer.

My question is:

> For any connected graph (undirected graph), is its adjacency matrix diagonalizable?

Note: it is obviously that it does not have to be full rank, for example a tree graph.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer is yes for undirected graphs, since the adjacency matrix of a finite undirected graph (not necessarily connected) is a symmetric real matrix.